# How to access an object value by a key and return its specific value type

Tags: typescript

What I want to achieve is getting a valid intellisense for an object value - in this case a function signature - if I try to access the value by the object's key. Below is an example that should illustrate what I'm up to. I came to this code more by trial and error, but what I really don't understand is why it is working outside the `Bar` constructor and fails within.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmWBeGBvAsAKBjATgUwEMATALhgAoBKGJAPjT3ygFdcwYBGGAXwBosOAO644UfOQoA3QgBsWEmGBYBbAEb5cNeowKt2vLDyxZQkWNFy00gpiUnaGqJvo4AiAGYgQb3gOwwImKK0nIK5JYIAOaOusxsHMaYSabg0DBQAJ4ADvgQ1hgBCFD+OJZGANwmmFm5MAAqOXnWtfggHhlNEFU1TQ1NANL4mfkoANbD7f253Vit0-gAamHNKI0zANrr+EMjALo91R4sYMBQcOAwUczbADz1MPgAHuJgxPnbuxB0FJbk9VR-l0tnsbEUOr8oFYEJ0ZjRCjgcHoEpRWvlCOiwJkqBtLAdbCkAlAABa4EBCJT4CkAUVwZNwFAABgBVMBjMDkjjzADkABJUJYeNzGVQeoTUuYYF4QNZrlBthQ3MU3KKsNKAHRBcQUTiinAAen1gVE2pk8kUynUmkBMCkIDgxBgAFonQwot5iHx4Ih8LJZHAIPhIPgYBBieT8iSQ6IosTYMdTudLhA4FEwIR9PhqmZ0mpCFYUHKFW5LCqenncJqTfhFRWyzBDcbgqFzREodEbXaHc7XVcPV7ir7-YHg6Hw0JI8To6m41KTmcLhwU2mM2ws5hs7IMfkAEKEABeYJwOahLDOIAZrSBuS+1iViBVR8RJ4yspuTQorVVARwUCrzYAJhoBsjS1GszXCSkpGtcgu0dF0GDzT1AhAFhZEdZ5cjODIZSEC8xhgDFCLUEBoIJIwsCAA)

```js
const int = {
  read: () => { return 1 },
  write: (value: number) => { return }
}

const str = {
  read: () => { return "foo" },
  write: (value: string) => { return }
}

const types = {
  int,
  str
};

type Types = typeof types;
type TypeKeys = keyof Types;
type TypeValues = Types[TypeKeys];


function getType<T extends TypeKeys>(str: T): Types[T] {
  if (str in types) {
    return (types as any)[str];
  }

  throw new Error(`Unknown type '${str}'`);
}


const foo = getType("int");
foo.write(1);  // write(value: number): void --> good, intellisense shows the right function signature

const bar = getType("str");
bar.write("bar"); // write(value: string): void --> good, intellisense shows the right function signature


class Baz {
  constructor(type: TypeKeys = "int") {
    const t = getType(type);
    if (type === "int") {
      t.write(2);  // write(value: never): void --> bad, would expect to work as above
    } else {
      t.write("foo");  // write(value: never): void --> bad, would expect
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when someone calls `new Baz("str")`?

Comment: It's not about what happens when creating a new Baz instance, what's not working is the intellisense or typing of the `t.write` inside the `Baz` constructor. Outside the constructor - let's say the global scope - I get a valid intellisense for `t.write`. I suspect that it has someting to do with the `TypeKeys` type of `constructor(type: TypeKeys = "int")`. Hope that makes sense ...

Comment: Well, if I call `new Baz("str")` it will call `getType("str")` which returns `types.str`, which has a `write` method accepting a string, not a number. But you are calling `write` with the number 2. So, what do you expect to happen in this case? Typescript is telling you your code does something wrong, and your code *is* doing something wrong.

Comment: I edited the constructor code and I hope it's more understandable now. Yes, I know that my code is doing something wrong :-)

Comment: It's weird that this is focusing on IntelliSense instead of the fact that the compiler gives errors.  That is, it wants `never` in a place that it "shouldn't".  Getting the types to work out seems more important than IntelliSense, although once the types are handled then you could hope that some solution to the type will also improve IntelliSense.

Comment: @jcalz Yes, I have to agree that intellisense is not the best term in this context - sure it's about the types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `Baz` constructor, the `type` parameter is of the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `TypeKeys`.  And the `t` variable is therefore of the union type `TypeValues`.  Now, your expectation is that you can check the type of `type` and it will have an implication for the type of `t`, because the type of `type` and the type of `t` are *correlated* to each other.  But the compiler really does not tend to track such a correlation across different union-typed variables; this is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  There's no way to get IntelliSense if the compiler doesn't know what's going on.

---

Up to and including TypeScript 4.5, the only ways to deal with this were either redundant but type safe, or terse but unsafe.  Here's redundant but safe:

```
  if (type === "int") {
    const t = getType(type);
    t.write(2);
  } else {
    const t = getType(type);
    t.write("foo");
  }
```

Here we've duplicated the `const t = getType(type);` line and pushed it down into the scope after checking `type === "int"`.  Since `type` is already narrowed to either `"int"` or `"str"`, then the two `getType(type)` lines are seen to return narrower types, and everything just works.  Personally I think this is probably a reasonable approach, especially if you're planning to already have `if`/`else` blocks where you write code for individual cases.  And this is probably the only way that gives you the IntelliSense you want.

---

Here's terse but unsafe:

```
const t = getType(type) as typeof int & typeof str; // assert
if (type === "int") {
  t.write(2);
} else {
  t.write("foo");
}
```

Here we've used a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to lie to the compiler and say that `t` is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the two types instead of the union.  That would mean you could `write()` a `number` to it or a `string` to it as you see fit.  In actuality only one of those will work, and luckily the rest of the code does the right thing.  That assertion doesn't duplicate things, but it's unsafe (e.g., you could switch around `if (type === "int")` to `if (type !== "int")` and the compiler wouldn't notice.  As I said, I'd probably prefer the redundant version to this.  Here the compiler will be happy with either a `number` or a `string`, so the IntelliSense will be too loose.

---

Starting in TypeScript 4.6, a fix at [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) will be released that gives a way to get safe correlated union behavior.  But you do have to refactor some of your types and type annotations to get it to work, so that the compiler is aware that you're looking for this behavior.  You need to write a basic mapping type like this:

```
type TypeMap = { int: number, str: string };
```

And then you can define your other types in terms of it:

```
type Types = { [K in keyof TypeMap]: {
  read: () => TypeMap[K],
  write: (value: TypeMap[K]) => void
} };
type TypeKeys = keyof Types;
```

Then your `types` and `getType()` stay the same (but it's important that you annotate the return type of `getType()` in terms of `Types`:

```
const types = {
  int,
  str
};

function getType<K extends TypeKeys>(str: K): Types[K] {
  return types[str];
}
```

And then you can write a generic `writeType()` function like this:

```
function writeType<K extends TypeKeys>(type: K) {
  const t = getType(type);
  const vals = { int: 2, str: "foo" };
  t.write(vals[type]) // okay in TS4.6+
}
```

Notice how I've refactored the `if`/`else` clause to be a lookup in an object.  The correlation between `t` and `vals[type]` is now tracked by the compiler and there's no error.  This really sidesteps the whole IntelliSense thing, because you're calling the function exactly once, on something that needs to be correlated to `t`.

And you can invoke this function inside your `Baz` constructor (you can't make the `Baz` constructor do it inline unless you make all of `Baz` generic):

```
class Baz {
  constructor(type: TypeKeys = "int") {
    writeType(type);
  }
}
```

So that's neat.  Personally with the example code as written I'd probably still go with the "redundant" version on the top, since the extra code is minimal. But it's good to see that it's at least possible for the compiler to follow the sort of correlated union manipulation that you're doing here.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.0-dev.20220116#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBFJLwD2wUALkgJbC0C8eJpSAThCACYBcSABQBKJEwB8eThGoBXDsCQBGJAF8ANG1IB3DnWoQBggG6ZZhpMFlgARhA6iJUrnIVq2qomwpVaNDmKshOzSvEaOkrjSrooARABm5OSxaprB7Lr6FiZmFv4MAOYRzjLyip7pFd6UNEjUAJ4w0IEE6aQM1Gkh-h4A3F7pDU1IACqNzSxDEOTxdeNQ-YPjo+MA0hD1UIEA1hszK00LbFMHEABquVssY4cA2jcQ65sAuosDpPGywPDUdJRIBRkDwAPKskBAAB4GYA8LYPJ5QcSCfwCVbCAQPKC3VbPIIhOizZHUAIMOaHUStEKkFxlIRTLYgBnAerCW7+V5adzENp1AAWHHI2ksECFAFEOAKOIIAAYAVWA22AgsUJwA5AASXD+VSq6XCRakKrc0g+WqJciBQHUB6CWIdWL6tjmgB0mQMgiU+tIAHpvUg3RAchhzAIrLZ7OikMZyHQeEgALTxyQFJI8dT0RgQDAYOhQCBUZBQXmCrbUXnIPQFXm0T7fX7-KB0AqgVwQd5kGq0GwgAIsK022L+B0GpDdjiuvTu2Jj4dIX3+yeB0zBvLEwqR6OxhNJgGp9MdLM5vMFpBFkt8itN6tIWs-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-kidadEMXdIF+cumFRB0AjsedxICAkSQpKo+vSZVS6YFiUzPMIyM2WQ5mQdB6t2Q5Tkq4rmPZWR6s6IuNp64pDVi0aAyqEAA)

Answer (score 1):

If you give the union a discriminant, then that can be used in the `if` statement to narrow the type of `t` as you want to. The `as const` assertions are needed so that the `type` properties are not widened to `string`.

```
const int = {
  type: 'int',
  read: () => { return 1 },
  write: (value: number) => { return },
} as const

const str = {
  type: 'str',
  read: () => { return "foo" },
  write: (value: string) => { return },
} as const

// ...

class Baz {
  constructor(type: TypeKeys = "int") {
    const t = getType(type);
    if (t.type === "int") {
      t.write(2);
    } else {
      t.write("foo");
    } 
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlmWBeGBvAsAKBjKBPABwFMAuGAcgSnIBoscAnIgQwBMyAKAShiQD40MJlACuDMDACMMAL51sMAO4M4UUjA4A3ZgBsR6sCIC2AIyIMe-QcLES5WGTGYQYoSFCxY30GNAa80elxCdXI-WiCmNk5LAVQhIlFxGAAiADMQEBTZeRxlVXUtXX0yPwQAc1jrRNschycXbw9ML3AffGIXFAwFKlzfKAYHAG5PTA6iGAAVEK7g4hA0+aIIUfGQ6ZCAaSI8OYBrXcXNzrWJk6IANWKVgJnOgG17oh29gF01sbSRMGAoOHAMHKiWeAB4pjAiAAPNRgVguZ6vCB8Dh+MhTLjo2ZPN6BXpLVGDeASCYQHg9HCMGrJDikhpOMB4LgPPwfIIyMY4KAACwYIEUMDARAFAFEGHyGBwAAYAVTA+zA-JJG3IABJUH4ZOQpVw1hyWgamjAMiAAsCoM8OCkqCldVgTQA6fJqDiSXU4AD0HqUKhd2j0BmMZgsZE0IDgrBgAFoowJyplWDRiWodDo4BAiJBJhBufyXDzJipytzYN9fv9ARA4OUwMwkkQxkaTMx-ChzZaUn5bWtmwwnb6iFbe92YF6fQUigHSoMKpiYGGI9HY0CE0mqERU+nMxnfLnFPnuYXqyXjT8-gCJFWa3WxA2DV4dM4XAAhZgALzxOCaDBEfxAkomLFiCRAJrUQW1P0pI1kCBEEQlpEI7QUHA4AJKAHXOJAsNSG1ySCSlcH7CcACYkIIxwNx3CkCMI51B3STJu3w2QYHZBwsCAA)